# How to use response body in another screen

Tags: json, http, flutter

I am trying to use the response.body from a request made in network.dart in main.dart, but it does not seem to work here is my code

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


class Network {
  var data;

  Future fetchData() async {

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: "application/json",
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
    };
    http.Response response = await http.get (url),
      headers: headers,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = response.body;
      return jsonDecode(data);

    } else {
      print('this is the ${response.statusCode}');
    }

  }
}
```

in the main.dart i am trying to print network.data but its null and when mapping json values i get all nulls what am i missing

Edit below i am assigning a var called body to to the result of the fetchdata in hte network but it does not seem to work when i print i run i get this "Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future'"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foodicsclimamethod/networking.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Network network = Network();
  String productName;
  int productPrice;
  String productData;

  void updateUi() async {
    Future<dynamic> body = await network.fetchData();
    print(body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    network.fetchData();
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for your question! Is there any chance that you could include a code sample showing the `main.dart` file?

Comment: edited the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with the `updateUi` method in your code sample. The `body` variable is typed as `Future<dynamic>`, however it should be `dynamic` because you are awaiting the `fetchData` method. If you wanted to, you could avoid specifying a type altogether and simply use [`final`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference) in order to infer the type. I have included a complete example below showing how this could all fit together:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Network {
  Future fetchData() async {
    final headers = <String, String>{
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
    };

    final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Error();
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future _future;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _future = Network().fetchData();
  }
}
```